# Batch File Copy User Profiles With an Age Limitations

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I thought this would be easy but I'm stuck. I have a batch file that will let me back up all 'Actual' (not system) user profiles which is fine & working good. However, an age limitation to the profile folders being backed up has to be applied. Only backing up all the user profiles folder with a last modified date of 60 days is allowed, rather just blind copying the whole lot (time & disk space etc.)

I thought adding the /MAXAGE switch to the robocopy line would suffice but seems even if the profile is recently active (within the date copy criteria) important files older than 60 days within the folder structures are left out - which is not good!

I had a look into Forfiles which seemed would be useable but doesn't deal with folder dates, just files (it seems?). Also the Dir /T:W switch but outputs syntax I can't blend into the current batch file.

Here is the code...

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
color 5F
for /F "Skip=1 Tokens=* Delims=\" %%G in (
'"WMIc Path Win32_UserProfile Where (Special!='True') Get LocalPath"'
    ) Do for /F "delims= " %%H in ("%%G") do (
for /F "Tokens=3,4 delims=\" %%I in ("%%H") do (
robocopy "%%H" "C:\IT\%%I" /XD AppData /XD "Application Data" /XD "Local Settings" /XD *Drive* /MAXAGE:60 /E /R:0 /XA:SH
    )   
  )
)
pause
```

So my question is, how can I make it check the last modified date of a user profile folder & back it up (including subfolders/files that maybe older than 60 days) as long as the root user profile folder has modified attribute within the last 60 days, else older, dont back up.

Hope that makes sense, thanks for any info / tips anyone may advise.

```
C:\Users\Admin   Last Mod 12/12/2020 (>backup)
C:\Users\Dez.Smith Last Mod 19/11/2020 (>backup)
c:\Users\Smiley.Pippet Last Mod 16/09/2020 (<dont backup)

etc....
```

New Code...

```
@echo off
color 5F
for /f "tokens=2 delims==;." %%a in ('"wmic path Win32_UserProfile where (Special!='True' and LastUseTime is not null) get LastUseTime,LocalPath /VALUE | find "LastUseTime""') Do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path Win32_UserProfile where (Special!='True' and LastUseTime is not null) get LastUseTime,LocalPath /VALUE | find "LocalPath""') Do (
echo %%a
pause
if %%a GTR 20200109230000 echo %%b
    )
    )
)
pause
```

From the output of the command I get

```
LastUseTime=20201212194437.654000+000
LocalPath=C:\Users\Admin
```

I was thinking I can strip that into what I need. So have trimmed the date to just 20201212194437 & also just C:\Users\Admin.

If I set a number to 60 days or what ever 20200109230000 (%%a) (1st Sept 11:00pm 00 secs) I thought I could use the GTR switch against it to then robocopy %%b
but it doesn't echo back...Not sure whats happening as if I echo %%a & %%b they resolve the snippets I want...cheers

Comment: It sounds to me as if you may be better off just backing them all up using Robocopy, and letting it handle the rest. If you take a look at its file selection options, you should consider its `/M`, and/or possibly its `/XC`, `/XN`, `/XO`, `/XX`, `/XL`, `/IS`, and `/IT` options.

Comment: The `/MAXAGE` option of `robocopy` is used on a per-file basis. But you could query the `LastUseTime` property: `wmic path Win32_UserProfile where "Special!=TRUE and LastUseTime is not null" get LastUseTime,LocalPath /VALUE`; this requires some date arithmetics, but it is possible particularly because of the returned standardised locale-independent date/time format…

Comment: Just take account that it is possible, through various means, that files within a users profile directory could conceivably be modified when the user did not log in. So don't just accept that if they've not logged in no files could have been modified, added, or removed.

Comment: thanks! I'm getting somewhere with aschipfl, but getting stuck again, have updated OP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script might accomplish what you want (see the `rem`-comments in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TARGET=D:\Backup\Profiles" & rem // (destination directory of the backup)
set /A "_MAXAGE=60"              & rem // (maximum age in days of user profile)

rem // Retrieve current date/time:
for /F "delims=" %%U in ('
    wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get LocalDateTime /VALUE
') do for /F "delims=" %%V in ("%%U") do set "%%V"
rem // Loop through non-special non-roaming user profiles:
for /F "delims=" %%U in ('
    wmic path Win32_UserProfile where "Special=FALSE and RoamingConfigured=FALSE and LastUseTime is not null and LocalPath is not null" ^
        get LastUseTime^,LocalPath /VALUE
') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%V in ("%%U") do (
    rem // Store current item, which can be the last usage date or the source path:
    set "%%V=%%W" & set "Name=%%~nxW" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check what the current item is:
    if "%%V"=="LastUseTime" (
        endlocal
        rem // Current item is last usage date, so get difference to current date:
        call set /A "RelUseDate=(((%LocalDateTime:~,4%*12+%LocalDateTime:~4,2%)*36525+%LocalDateTime:~6,2%00)-((%%LastUseTime:~,4%%*12+%%LastUseTime:~4,2%%)*36525+%%LastUseTime:~6,2%%00))/100"
    ) else if !RelUseDate! leq %_MAXAGE% (
        rem // Current item is source path, so copy when last usage data is not too long ago:
        ECHO robocopy "!LocalPath!" "!_TARGET!\!Name!" *.* /PURGE /XD "AppData" /XJ
        endlocal
    ) else endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```